# ProgramA executes ProgramB at command line with -variables. How can I find what variables it's using?

Tags: windows

So, a specific game program runs another program (it's the same game, with two programs). The first program, ProgramA, runs a second program, ProgramB, with a huge long list of variables (I know one of them is -runtime). How can I know all of the variables it's using with the second program?

Comment: Tim's answer sounds reasonable, I'd try that. I think this question may be better suited to Superuser than SO though.

Comment: @Amicable: Thanks for the comment. I have updated the answer to include a solution that relies on tools rather than writing code. I guess that's what you meant when you said this question is maybe better suited for Superuser.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace ProgramB with your own program that dumps the command line to a file/console/GUI. This should do if you only need to inspect the command line parameters once.

If you need to have a working solution that doesn't interfere with normal operation you should have your own program start the original ProgramB passing along the command line parameters you were given.

---

Update: For a solution that does not involve writing any code you can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to inspect properties of running processes. Right-clicking on a process and selecting *Properties* from the menu will show - among others - the command line used to start the process.